# Solr schema error 'unknown field 'id'

Tags: solr

When trying to populate a solr index we are running into the following error on our local dev instances.

`courses_master_index_shard1_replica_n1: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core courses_master_index_shard1_replica_n1: Can't load schema managed-schema: unknown field 'id'`

Building the schema also fails.

When we go to our UAT / PROD instances everything is working correctly. I've included a section of our `search.config` below where 'id' is specified?

```
                    <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <!-- This element must be first -->
                    <typeMatches hint="raw:AddTypeMatch">
                        <typeMatch typeName="guidCollection"     type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]"     fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="textCollection"     type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"   fieldNameFormat="{0}_txm" multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="stringCollection"   type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"   fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="intCollection"      type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]"    fieldNameFormat="{0}_im"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="guid"               type="System.Guid"                                        fieldNameFormat="{0}_s"                                         settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="id"                 type="Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Kernel"                  fieldNameFormat="{0}_s"                                         settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="shortid"            type="Sitecore.Data.ShortID, Sitecore.Kernel"             fieldNameFormat="{0}_s"                                         settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="string"             type="System.String"                                      fieldNameFormat="{0}_s"                                         settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="text"               type="System.String"                                      fieldNameFormat="{0}_t"   cultureFormat="_{1}"                  settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="int"                type="System.Int32"                                       fieldNameFormat="{0}_tl"                                        settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="bool"               type="System.Boolean"                                     fieldNameFormat="{0}_b"                                         settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="datetime"           type="System.DateTime"                                    fieldNameFormat="{0}_tdt" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFF'Z'" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="long"               type="System.Int64"                                       fieldNameFormat="{0}_tl"                                        settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="float"              type="System.Single"                                      fieldNameFormat="{0}_tf"                                        settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="double"             type="System.Double"                                      fieldNameFormat="{0}_td"                                        settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="stringArray"        type="System.String[]"                                    fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="intArray"           type="System.Int32[]"                                     fieldNameFormat="{0}_im"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="datetimeArray"      type="System.DateTime[]"                                  fieldNameFormat="{0}_dtm" multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="datetimeCollection" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_dtm" multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                        <typeMatch typeName="coordinate"         type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Data.Coordinate, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Data" fieldNameFormat="{0}_rpt"                      settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                    </typeMatches>

                    <!-- This allows you to map a field name in Sitecore to the index and store it in the appropriate way -->
                    <!-- Add schema fields here to enable multi-language processing -->
                    <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
                        <field fieldName="__created_by"         returnType="string" />
                        <field fieldName="__smallcreateddate"   returnType="datetime" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH\:mm\:ss'Z'" />
                        <field fieldName="__smallupdateddate"   returnType="datetime" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH\:mm\:ss'Z'" />
                        <field fieldName="__workflow_state"     returnType="string" />
                        <field fieldName="extension"            returnType="text" />
                        <field fieldName="title"                returnType="text" />
                        <field fieldName="type"                 returnType="text" />
                    </fieldNames>

                    <!-- FIELD TYPE MAPPING
                         This allows you to map a field type in Sitecore to a type in the index.
                         USAGE: When you add new field types to Sitecore, add the mappings here so they work through the Linq Layer 
                      -->
                    <fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldTypeName">
                        <fieldType fieldTypeName="checkbox"                                                                                                 returnType="bool"             />
                        <fieldType fieldTypeName="date|datetime"                                                                                            returnType="datetime"         />
                        <fieldType fieldTypeName="html|rich text|single-line text|multi-line text|text|memo|image|reference"                                returnType="text"             />
                        <fieldType fieldTypeName="word document"                                                                                            returnType="text"             />
                        <fieldType fieldTypeName="integer"                                                                                                  returnType="long"             />
                        <fieldType fieldTypeName="number"                                                                                                   returnType="float"            />
                        <fieldType fieldTypeName="icon|droplist|grouped droplist"                                                                           returnType="string"           />
                        <fieldType fieldTypeName="checklist|multilist|treelist|tree list|treelistex|tree list|multilist with search|treelist with search"   returnType="stringCollection" />
                        <fieldType fieldTypeName="name lookup value list|name value list"                                                                   returnType="stringCollection" />
                        <fieldType fieldTypeName="droplink|droptree|grouped droplink|tree"                                                                  returnType="stringCollection" />
                    </fieldTypes>
                </fieldMap>
```

Also here is the field listed in solr.

[image]

Comment: Are you using SolrCloud / ZooKeeper?

Comment: Have you compared schemas between environments? The ID that you show as being specifdied is the TYPE called ID, not the field called ID. Check other environment configs to see if ID is added in raw:AddFieldByFieldName. Or check to see if they have set indexAllFields to true.